# How to evaluate this partial derivative in terms of polar coordinates

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, chain-rule

How to evaluate this partial derivative in terms of polar coordinates?

[image: Image of a math problem]

How to solve this question?

Comment: I think I have the solution but I can't find the solution for the problem so I would like someone to give me the answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be better for you in the long run if you post your (attempted) solutions. Then we know how to help or how to explain misconceptions you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chain rule says that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$.

Here, $z= ln(x+ 2y)$ so $frac{1}{x+2y}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= \frac{2}{x+ 2y}$.  $x= r cos(\theta)$ so $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}= cos(\theta)$ and $y= r sin(\theta)$ so $\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}= -r sin(\theta)$.

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}= \frac{cos(\theta)}{x+ 2y}+ \frac{2 sin(\theta)}{x+ 2y}$.

If you want that entirely in terms of r and $\theta$, replace x with $r cos(\theta)$ and replace y with $r sin(\theta)$:
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}= \frac{cos(\theta)}{r(cos(theta)+ 2sin(\theta))}+ \frac{sin(\theta)}{r(cos(theta)+ 2sin(\theta))}$.